# Converting usize into f32

Tags: rust

I have implemented the following function that calculates the mean of a sequence:

```
fn mean<T, R>(seq: &[T]) -> R
    where R: Div<R, Output=R> + From<T> + From<usize> + Sum<R>
{
    let total: R = seq.iter().map(|&x| R::from(x)).sum()
    let size = R::from(seq.len())
    total / size
}
```

However, I'm having trouble when converting the `usize` that is returned from `seq.len()`

```
let numbers = vec![10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60];
let result: f32 = mean(&numbers);
println!("{:?}", result);
```

```
5  | fn mean<T, R>(seq: &[T]) -> R
   |    ----
6  |     where R: Div<R, Output=R> + From<T> + From<usize> + Sum<R>
   |                                           ----------- required by this bound in `mean`
...
15 |     let result: f32 = mean(&numbers);
   |                       ^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<usize>` is not implemented for `f32`
```

I'm quite blocked by this since I'm still a beginner with traits. How can I solve this specific problem? (if it can be done)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `f32` does not implement `From<usize>`. It does implement `From<i16>`, `From<i8>`, `From<u16>` and `From<u8>. This is because`f32` cannot represent all the values of a bigger integer exactly.

What you probably want is to use the `as` conversion, that allows for some precision loss. Unfortunately you cannot use `as` on generic types, only on primitive types.

You could write a trait to do all the necessary `as` conversions manually... But of course there is a [crate](https://docs.rs/num-traits/0.2.11/num_traits/cast/trait.AsPrimitive.html) for that! With `num_traits::cast::AsPrimititve` your code becomes:

```
fn mean<T, R>(seq: &[T]) -> R
    where R: Div<R, Output=R> + Sum<R> + Copy + 'static,
          T: AsPrimitive<R>,
          usize: AsPrimitive<R>
{
    let total: R = seq.iter().map(|&x| x.as_()).sum();
    let size = seq.len().as_();
    total / size
}
```

I have added the `Copy` constraints, that I think you missed in your code, and also the `'static` for `R` that is required for `AsPrimitive`.

Comment: Please search for duplicates and mark them as such before answering questions.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to represent every possible `i32` value in `f32` format. 
That's the reason why `From` trait implementation provided for `f32` supports only `i16`/`u16`/`i8`/`u8`.

`i32` and `f32` have the same amount of bytes but usually f32 spent few bytes for exponent so it can't represent all numbers from `i32`. [Single-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: Please search for duplicates and mark them as such before answering questions.